# Select an object, but exclude specific members in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, select, orm

I want to select an object using Hibernate, but exclude some of it's members (in my case, a collection). The model object is used extensively in my application, so i don't want to change the mappings. 
Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Is the collection eager or lazy loaded?

Answer (score 1):

You can always drop back to HQL especially if this is a read-only use-case.
HQL lets you do basically create an SQL query to return only the fields that you need, but it is safer than raw SQL and does not bypass Hibernate but works in conjunction with the ORM core.

You would use a SELECT clause to get only the attributes that you need.

Comment: I am using HQL. My query looks like this:

 `String queryString = String.format("SELECT rd FROM %s rd WHERE rd.id = :runId", RunData.class.getName());`

But this returns the whole RunData object along with it's associations.

Comment: @sebi then specify only the fields that are required in you query.

Comment: They are quite a few... Is there no way to specify the fields to **exclude**?

Comment: Maybe you need a tutorial: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/hibernate/hibernate_query_language.htm skip down to the part about SELECT

Comment: Regarding the question about exclude. If this is a problem perhaps you should split this object into two parts, one part with the most commonly used attributes and the other part with the least commonly used ones.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure you can do what you want without changing the mappings. Personally I would change the mappings to be lazy rather than eager as you can easily override lazy loads. Assuming you're using HQL for the most part (since you say you're using it already), you can then keep the eager loading by adding `fetch <field-name>` in the `from` section of your HQL, then simply not add the fetch to HQL where you specifically want lazy loading. Of course, this kind of change would require communicating it to your team as any new queries should consider whether they need eager or lazy loads, but overall it shouldn't be terribly disruptive.